# Is POP3 protocol necessary to implement in mail server?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, pop3, mail-server

I'm currently researching how to implement a mail server in .net, I know SMTP protocol is necessary to follow its rules described in detail in RFC white-papers. But what about POP3? I want to write my mail client by myself, So there is no reason that other mail client can access my mail server (as I said before it's just a research). I want to know, Is it possible to implement my own protocol instead of using POP3 ?

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: I wan to say a huge thank you for all your replies, I wish I could mark all your replies as great answers. Thank you for awesome answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your server and your client, you can do anything you want!

Seriously though, all other servers will talk to you over SMTP (RFC 821 and 2821) so that's about all that you need. POP3 and IMAP are client-only so if you're going to build your protocol/interface you can skip those.

Comment: Also, *definitely* include some logging code for every SMTP transaction. I've built my own SMTP server before, too, and you will see some very unexpected things. For instance, RFC 2821 says that it doesn't "add new or change existing functionality" from 821 but then goes on to say that some features from 821 that weren't common are still valid but you have to dig them up in the old docs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; POP3 is only used by email clients.

For a long time, AOL did not support POP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I said, I implement my own mail client. in this case will I have to implement POP3 again ? It's not important for me which other mail clients can use my mail server.

Comment: Your mail client can do anything it wants, as long as it reads mail (IMAP is popular).  However, note that your users may prefer to use Outlook or Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have to do is whatever is necessary to fulfill the requirements of your project.  It sounds like you don't think POP3 is necessary.  Therefore, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you client is the only client accessing your mailserver you are absolutely free to implement whatever protocols you want... even SMTP is only necessary if the server you implement need to talk to other servers/client...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement your mail client application you don't need to follow the rules.